# Finder Problems after Updating to Yosemite

Tags: finder, macos, software-update

I updated to Yosemite from Mavericks. Everything seems to be working normally, except `Finder`. When I open a `Finder` window it is empty. Even if I open the `Applications` folder - it is empty. 
The files on my desktop also look normal. When I open Pages and then go to open a file I can then navigate to i.e. my `Documents` folder and I see all the files normally. Just when I use `Finder` directly it does not display anything.

I created a folder on my desktop and placed a file in it. When I opened the folder I could not see its contents. Once I `chmod 777` the folder using terminal - I was able to see everything.

Shared folders on the network however display files correctly. I am assuming something is wrong with the permissions of the user.

I tried rebooting with `CMD` `Alt` `P` `R` and also booted into the recovery partition and repaired the user permissions. I even deleted the `Finder` preferences plist - no luck.

I tried googling, but I could not find similar situations - any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do other user accounts have the same issues?

Comment: There is no other user account on the mac

Comment: "I as able" should spell "I am able" ?

Comment: Added a user account - and that user can see all files.

Comment: Have you tried a 'Fix Permissions' in disk utility?

Comment: yes... had no effect.

Comment: Lots of discussion here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6632605?start=0&tstart=0 ... no real solutions so far, but switching Finder into the "List" view is a good workaround for now.